# Git: set branch to current ref

Tags: git

Due to the use of submodules in my projects I'm finding myself often on "(no branch)". As I'm also adding code to those submodules I'm committing in there. When I then want to push those submodules I need to be on a branch of course. Hence my question:

Is there a way/shortcut in git (command line) to set a local branch to the current commit/HEAD without the detour of

```
git checkout the_branch
git reset --hard <previous commit-ish>
```

To be more precise, my real problem with the above "detour" is that I'm temporarily leaving the original HEAD with the checkout-command. That can be avoid with the `git branch -f` command (thanks to CharlesB).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Checkout the branch with `-B`: this will reset the branch to HEAD, which is the current ref.

```
git checkout -B <branch>
```

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt):

> If -B is given,  is created if it doesn’t exist;
>   otherwise, it is reset. This is the transactional equivalent of
>
> ```
> $ git branch -f <branch> [<start point>]
> $ git checkout <branch>
> ```
>
> that is to say, the branch is not reset/created unless "git
>   checkout" is successful.

Comment: I now realize the "branch -f" command is what I'm looking for, because my real problem is that I don't want to "leave" the commit on which I'm currently sitting. Thanks.

Comment: Link to official documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt

Answer (score 27):

```
git checkout -B the_branch HEAD
```

This will checkout `the_branch` at commit HEAD, even if `the_branch` pointed somewhere else before. It was added in one of the last few git releases, so you might not have it available. An alternate route would be `git branch -D the_branch && git checkout -b the_branch`

Comment: I'm using git version 1.7.0.4 and checkout -B does not yet exists. But it's nice to see that it will be in the future.